# Why does MySQL time diff return greater than an hour for two times across the hour boundary?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, time

I run

```
select timestamp('2013-10-17 19:00:45') - timestamp('2013-10-17 18:59:37');
```

And it returns

```
4108.000000
```

Why?  It's not a leap day, `timestamp` is the correct function, and subtracting works for times that don't cross an hour boundary.

One fix here is to use `unix_timestamp` instead of `timestamp`. But that still doesn't explain what weird thing is happening here.

Comment: SLaks is right, it's just the result of the _integer_ calculation: `20131017190045 - 20131017185937 = 4108`. Use the time diff functions provided to you by MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you subtract datetimes, it first converts them to numbers in the form:

```
YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu
```

So you're seeing this result:

```
mysql> select 20131017190045.000000 - 20131017185937.000000 diff;
+-------------+
| diff        |
+-------------+
| 4108.000000 |
+-------------+
```